# Errors while following UWP tutorial

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019, uwp-xaml

I am following the documentation for learning Universal Window Platform provided by Microsoft,
 and trying to make a simple [navigation app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages) (following the tutorial). I followed each and every step very carefully, but still getting some erors.
 The errors, I am getting is shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ri9j.png).

Comment: Those errors have clear messages and the error codes can be found online, with tips on how to resolve them. If you can't resolve one of them, please show the error (not an image of the error), the relevant code, and the steps you took to try to resolve it.

Comment: I am very beginner, but I resolved the issues following online instructions. Thanku @Rufus L

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes, my issue is resolved.

Comment: Good, You could post your answer below and mark yourself.